# CSS Media Query Execution

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm having an issue with a CSS media query where the general style is being applied after the media query despite being above the media query in the cascade.

### Example:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="myblock1">
    <div>Block 1</div>
    <div id="myblock2">Block 2</div>
    <div>Block 3</div>
</div>​
```

**CSS:**

```css
#myblock1 div {
    display:block;
    background-color:#F00;
}

@media (min-width:600px) {
    #myblock2 {
        display:none;
    }
}​
```

**Live demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7aWpQ/1/)**

In theory, all 3 blocks should be visible in windows of 600px width or less, and when larger the middle block should disappear, but that is not the case. Any ideas on why the ID/media query is being applied before the general styling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `#myblock1 div` is more specific than `#myblock2` (1 ID + 1 element vs 1 ID).

You'll either need to be more specific, or add `!important` on the rule you're trying to override.

- Be more specific: `#myblock1 #myblock2 { display: none; }`
- Use `!important`: `#myblock2 { display: none !important; }`

---

In my opinion, the best solution would be to make the outer container **less specific**, by giving it a class name, rather than an ID:

```
<div class="myblock1">
    <div>Block 1</div>
    <div id="myblock2">Block 2</div>
    <div>Block 3</div>
</div>​
```

Then, the following will work fine:

```
.myblock1 div {
    display:block;
    background-color:#F00;
}

@media (min-width:600px) {
    #myblock2 {
        display:none;
    }
}​
```

Comment: I wonder if people are going to start a debate in the comments here over whether it's worse practice to use multiple IDs for the sake of specificity or to use `!important` instead.

Comment: Both of these options work just fine, but I feel like they aren't quite right. In my experience IDs have always been the most specific way of applying something, and if you have to use !important you are doing something wrong, but in this case it's necessary. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @BoltClock: I usually like to avoid !important. I think the proper solution in this case is to have the first container have a `.className`, and the second one (the more specific one) have an `#id`, then you don't have that problem (since `#id` > ∞`.class`)

Comment: @DevinRodriguez: See the comment above for a more proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

Add `!important` to `display:none;` than it's working.

```
#myblock1 div {
display:block;
background-color:#F00;
}

@media (min-width:600px) {
    #myblock2 {
        display:none!important;
    }
}​
```

**Note:** Because the media query is less specific than your main css. ie. `#myblock1 #myblock2 { display:none; }` should also work

Comment: Because the media query is less specific than your main css. ie.   #myblock1 #myblock2 {
            display:none;
        } should also work

Comment: I already know that (I'm not the one who asked the question), but you should include that piece of information in your answer, rather than on a comment :)

Comment: It's not the media query (or the `@media` rule) that's less specific, it's the selector inside that rule.

Answer (score 0):

The specificity of your selector isn't high enough, so it isn't overriding your previous rule. Try this one instead:

```
@media (min-width:600px) {
    #myblock1 #myblock2 {
        display: none;
    }
}​
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7aWpQ/2/**